# JavaScript run calculation after radio button checked

Tags: javascript, radio-button, dom-events, compound-assignment

New to JavaScript and can't get my head around this exercise:
Need to modify JavaScript so it provides for the option buttons.  When the user selects yearly interest rate button, the application should compound the yearly rate and when the user clicks in Monthly button the application should compound the monthly rate.

I also need to display the results on the monthly and yearly compound calculation inside the text box

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Future Value Calculator</title>
<style type="text/css"> @import url("future_value.css");
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="future_value.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
<h1>Future Value Calculator</h1>
<p><input type="radio" name="calctype" id="monthly"
value="monthly" checked />Monthly Interest</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="calctype" id="yearly"
value="yearly" />Yearly Interest</p>
<p>Enter the values below and click "Calculate".</p>

<label for="investment">One-Time Investment:</label>
<select name="investment" id="investment"
<optgroup label="">
<option value="1000">$1,000</option>
<option value="5000">$5,000</option>
<option value="10000">$10,000</option>
<option value="25000">$25,000</option>
<option value="other">Other value</option>
</optgroup>
</select><br />

<label for="rate">Yearly Interest Rate:</label>
<select name="rate" id="rate"
<optgroup label="">
<option value="4%">4%</option>
<option value="6%">6%</option>
<option value="8%">8%</option>
<option value="10%">10%</option>
</optgroup>
</select><br />

<label for="years">Number of Years:</label>
<input type="text" id="years" /><br />

<label for="futureValue">Future Value:</label>
<input type="text" id="futureValue" disabled="disabled" /><br />

<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate" /><br />

<p><input type="checkbox" name="display" id="display" value="display"      checked />
Display both monthly and yearly results in the text area.</p>

<p>Results</p>
<textarea name="results" id="results" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var calculate_click = function () {

    var investment = parseFloat( $("investment").value );
    var annualRate = parseFloat( $("rate").value );
    var years = parseInt( $("years").value );

    $("futureValue").value = "";

    if (isNaN(investment) || investment <= 0) {
        alert("Investment must be a valid number\nand greater than zero.");
    } else if(isNaN(annualRate) || annualRate <= 0) {
        alert("Annual rate must be a valid number\nand greater than zero.");
    } else if(isNaN(years) || years <= 0) {
        alert("Years must be a valid number\nand greater than zero.");
    } else {
        var monthlyRate = annualRate / 12 / 100;
        var months = years * 12;
        var futureValue = investment;
        for ( i = 1; i <= months; i++ ) {
            futureValue = futureValue  * (1 + monthlyRate);
        }
        $("futureValue").value = futureValue.toFixed(2);
    } 
    if ( $("monthly").checked ) {
        $("futureValue").value = futureValueMonthly.toFixed(2);
    } else {
        $("futureValue").value = futureValueYearly.toFixed(2);
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    $("calculate").onclick = calculate_click;
    $("investment").focus();
    $("monthly").onclick;
}
```

Comment: To all readers: She's not using jQuery, she has her own `$` function that's just an abbreviation for `document.getElementById()`. Don't comment about incorrect selectors.

Comment: You've never set the variables `futureValueMonthly` and `futureValueYearly`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, you are correct.  I was trying to update my initial question to add all the variables, but not able to edit it

Comment: Click on the `edit` link below the question, you should be able to edit it.